# Proving trig identity with Euler cosine/sine fomulae

Tags: trigonometry

I am attempting to prove:

> $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$

using Euler's formula.

I used the formulae for cosine and sine and got the following equality:

$$\frac{\exp(i(a+b))+\exp(-i(a+b))}{2}=\frac{\exp(i(a-b))+\exp(i(b-a))}{2}$$

How do I finish off the proof?

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand,
$$e^{i(a+b)}=\cos(a+b)+i\sin(a+b).$$On the other hand, $$e^{i(a+b)}=e^{ia}e^{ib}=(\cos(a)+i\sin(a))(\cos(b)+i\sin(b))=(\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b))+i(\dots).$$
The real parts must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{e^{ia}+e^{-ia}}2\cdot\dfrac{e^{ib}+e^{-ib}}2-\left(\dfrac{e^{ia}-
e^{-ia}}{2i}\cdot\dfrac{e^{ib}-e^{-ib}}{2i}\right)$$

$$=\cdots$$

$$=2\cdot\dfrac{e^{i(a+b)}+e^{-i(a+b)}}4$$